# Read through small CSV file returns Regex too complicated

Tags: apex, batch, csv

I have a method which reads through a CSV file and if any of the columns match my keyset prepares them in an sObject, with my test files which contained 1,000 records but only 4 columns this worked fine, however increasing the number of columns now (22 columns) returns "**Regex too complicated**" despite only having around 100 rows.

How can I get around this issue? I have googled and found articles like [this](https://developer.financialforce.com/customizations/importing-large-csv-files-via-batch-apex/) but they are missing key parts of the code which renders this unusable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The regex too complicated error occurs when you reach 1,000,000 input sequences, which can occur even on incredibly small strings. For example, accord to the [knowledge article](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000005024&language=en_US&type=1):

```
Pattern pat = Pattern.compile('(A)?(B)?(C)?(D)?(E)?(F)?(G)?(H)?(I)?(J)?(K)?(L)?(M)?(N)?(O)?(P)?(Q)?(R)?(S)?(T)?(U)?(V)?(W)?(X)?(Y)?(Z)?(AA)?(AB)?(AC)?(AD)?(AE)?(AF)?(AG)?(AH)?(AI)?(AJ)?(AK)?(AL)?(AM)?(AN)?(AO)?(AP)?(AQ)?(AR)?(AS)?(AT)?(AU)?(AV)?(AW)?(AX)?(AY)?(AZ)?$');
Matcher mat = pat.matcher('asdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdf');
```

This code would fail because of the complexity of the pattern. Realistically, any Apex code that tries to parse a CSV is doomed to fail if it uses any regex matching on any reasonable sized file. Your best bet is to implement a [finite state](https://github.com/shannonspecht/CSVParser) parser to parse your CSV file (note: link goes to a Java-based finite state CSV parser, not written by me).

Because of the overhead of Apex, I wouldn't necessarily try to directly duplicate the Java-based version above, but hopefully it will get you started in a direction that will allow you to process larger CSV files more efficiently.

Your processing input loop can make use of a switch to implement a state engine efficiently:

```
public enum PARSER_STATE { BEGIN_FIELD, ERROR, FOUND_QUOTE, QUOTED_FIELD, UNQUOTED_FIELD }
Integer index = 0;
PARSER_STATE currentState = PARSER_STATE.BEGIN_FIELD;
while(index < input.size()) {
  String charAtX = input.substring(index, index+1);
  switch on currentState {
    when BEGIN_FIELD {
     ...
    }
    when FOUND_QUOTE {
     ...
    }
    ...
  }
}
```

Comment: N.B. I can recall solving this using a custom iterator/iterable and a batch class - works if each row can be considered independent of each other

Comment: @cropredy Yes, that's also viable. You just can't put a full csv through a single pattern.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is the best approach but what I have done is a custom iterator with a batch class and split each line  for processing (mentioned in my initial question).

This has allowed me to bypass the regex errors.